# return object true and string values in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to get the true value and string values same time.

```
return { info: info, true: true};
```

I am not sure this is ok or not. Let me know if I am a wrong, please give me an advice.

Here is a function.

```
isFunciton = function(data) {
if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined') {
    var matches = ko.utils.arrayFirst(aData(), function (item) {
        return data === item.data;
    });
    if (!matches) {
        return false;
    };
    var info = 'text';
    return {
        info: info,
        true: true
    };
};
return false; 
};
```

Comment: OK in what sense? Is it valid JavaScript? Yes. Does it make sense? Not really.

Comment: Blatant syntax error on line 1, "`funciton`"... If you want to know if it works, just try it and check the results. If you get errors and don't know (and can't find) why or what they mean, please do ask here, but provide error messages and desired vs actual behavior.

Comment: Correct the spelling of `isFunciton = funciton` to `isFunction = function `

Comment: Have you tried it?  Should work... if not, you can put quotes around the property name ( `{'true': true}` ) or just use a different property name (i.e. `{isTrue: true}`).    However, since the alternative is returning false, you really don't need to (at least in this example) - if it's not false it must be true, so you don't really need to specify it at that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always return an object, not sometimes a boolean and sometimes an object:

```
isFunction = function(data) {
    if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined') {
        var matches = ko.utils.arrayFirst(aData(), function (item) {
            return data === item.data;
        });
        if (!matches) {
            return {hasMatches:false};
        };
        var info = 'text';
        return {
            info: info,
            hasMatches: true
        };
    };
   return {hasMatches:false};
};
```

So you can always check the the return value `var val = isFunction(data)` with `if(val.hasMatches)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let obj = {
  true:true
}

console.log(obj.true)
console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

You can do a very simple testing as above to know the answer by yourself, which is yes, you can

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace  funciton with function

```
 isFunction = function (data) {
    if (typeof (data) !== 'undefined') {
        var matches = ko.utils.arrayFirst(aData(), function (item) {
            return data === item.data;
        });
        if (!matches) {
            return false;
        };
        var info = 'text';
        return {
            info: info,
            true: true
        };
    };
    return false; 
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an object an use it to return the values instead return true with info and false alone:

```
let obj = {
    info: string,
    somethingBoolean: boolean
}
```

and return the same object according to the need.